# Flatten List Erlang Need Clarification

Tags: erlang

```
flatten(X)               -> flatten(X,[]).

flatten([],Acc)          -> Acc;
flatten([[]|T],Acc)      -> flatten(T, Acc);
flatten([[_|_]=H|T],Acc) -> flatten(T, flatten(H,Acc));
flatten([H|T],Acc)       -> flatten(T,Acc++[H]) .
```

This is from an Post made before not my code.

Can some one explain what is happening here:

```
flatten([[_|_]=H|T],Acc)
```

`[[_|_]=H|T]` is the part I don't get.

(Also This is on another page but I can't comment on it because of rep.)

Answer (score 5):

`[[_|_]=H|T]` matches a non-empty list whose first element is also a non-empty list.

Let's split it up:

```
[      H|T]   %% match the Head and Tail of a list
 [_|_]        %% match the head and tail of the inner list, ignoring the values
      =       %% assign the matched inner list to the variable H
```

This is a common pattern in Erlang.  A list either has zero elements, and thus matches `[]`, or it has at least one element, in which case you can extract the first element and the rest of the list with `[H|T]`.  (That match can also be written as `[H] ++ T`.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just for further clarification if I was given this list: [[9,3,4]], on that line it would split like H=[] and T=[9,3,4]. Is that right?

Comment: The other way around: `H = [9,3,4]` and `T = []`.